# Delphi drawing a smooth pie

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawing

Does anyone have a code for drawing a smooth pie on a canvas in Delphi?

All I could find on the web are examples of smooth lines but that does not help me much...
Also I considered Gr32, but for what I need, it adds a pretty big footprint to my app.
I just need to draw a filled pie on a canvas that does not look so awful as it does with the default

```
Canvas.Pie(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4);
```

I use Delphi XE, so no Firemonkey...

**EDIT**
[image]

The pie on the left is obtained following your recommendation @johan using the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Center:TPoint;
    Radius:integer;
    Bmp: TBitmap;
    MF: TMetaFile;
    MetafileCanvas: TMetafileCanvas;
begin
  MF := TMetaFile.Create;
  MF.Width := 150;
  MF.Height := 150;

  MetafileCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(MF, 0);
  MetafileCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  MetafileCanvas.Pie(0,0,150, 150, 150,50, 150,50);

  MetafileCanvas.Free;

  Bmp := Gdip.DrawAntiAliased(MF);
  Image2.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
  Bmp.Free;
  MF.Free;
end;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This could be done easily with GDI+. The Key is using `SmoothingModeAntiAlias`:

```
uses GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  g: TGPGraphics;
  p: TGPPen;
  b: TGPBrush;
  r: TGPRect;
begin
  r := MakeRect(10, 10, ClientWidth - 20, ClientHeight - 20);
  g := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  g.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);  
  b := TGPSolidBrush.Create(aclGreen);
  p := TGPPen.Create(aclRed, 1);
  g.FillPie(b, r, 45, 90);
  g.DrawPie(p, r, 45, 90);
  b.Free;
  p.Free;
  g.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Tested with Delphi5

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

For drawing anti-aliased you can use: synopse gdiplus library, see: http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=GDI%2B

Here's an example:

```
implementation

uses 
  SynGDIPlus;  //provides gdip (see below)

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var Bmp: TBitmap;
    MF: TMetaFile;
    MetafileCanvas: TMetafileCanvas;
begin
  MF := TMetaFile.Create;
  MF.Width := 300;
  MF.Height := 200;

  MetafileCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(MF, 0);
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  MetafileCanvas.Pie(0,0,50, 50, 300,50, 200,50);
  MetafileCanvas.Free;

  Bmp := Gdip.DrawAntiAliased(MF);
  Image1.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
  Bmp.Free;
  //Image1.Picture.Assign(MF);

  MF.Free;
end;
```

Using this unit you only pull in that single unit, nothing more.
You don't have to use a metafile, you can also draw directly to a DC, internally SynGDIPlus does however use a metafile.

**Faster alternative**
If performance is an issue the Graphics32 library will be much faster.
http://graphics32.org/wiki/

I think that you worry far too much about the footprint of graphics32.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I needed. The pie drawn on the canvas is squarey... not smooth. I need a drawing function that will have smooth edges. Please check out the image I added to the question

Comment: What you call smooth the rest of the world calls anti-aliased. That is exactly what my answer provides. .Net does this by utilising GDI+, which, again, is exactly what the linked code in the answer provides.

Comment: Ok, then why does the image above show a pie drawn with your code that is not anti-aliased? It seems that the antialiased drawing is done AFTER the pie is drawn... I just changed the Brush style to solid in your code and changed the size, and the pie looks like the one in the left (in the above image) when it should look like the one in the right

Comment: Regarding Graphics32, besides the footprint, I have a small problem in  my IDE and I cannot seem to be able to install the gr32 package. I have no idea what is wrong with it, so I am searching for alternatives here. In the past I worked well with graphics32 and I'm sure I could solve my problem in no time using it... But then again... I should be able to have it installed in order to use it :(